# How to run static website on IISExpress with port smaller than 10240

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I'm trying to build a WebSite project in Visual Studio. This can be easily done by the add existing website command. IISExpress assigned a random port to my website, something like 45339.

I then try to change the port number to a number smaller than 10240 by editing the solution file, in my case the port number is 8630. I choose this number because this will be port we will use in production. I think it's nice to have development environment consistent with production environment. The change looks like this:

```
Project("{GUID}") = "Reports", "http://localhost:8630", "{GUID}"
```

This works fine. Apparently changing port to any number smaller than 10240 requires you to config an urlacl record, otherwise you will need admin privileges to start up the website.

I did that by executing below command in command line:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://mypc:8630/ user=everyone
```

This works fine. Now I can launch my website by click F5 in Visual Studio. But when I try to browse the webpage in browser, I got an error saying `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` This frustrates me because all I got here is a static web site, it's not possible to cause an server error...

I tried to change the port back to another number greater than 10240, in my case 10300. It works perfectly fine. I don't need to config any urlacl record, and the web page shows perfectly fine in the browser, no http 503 errors..

What did I miss to get this working?

More information:
I am using Visual Studio 2013, with IIS 8.0 Express on a Windows 7. And I don't have admin privileges all the time.

Comment: What was the initial problem that made you think you had to go down this route? http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges Seems to imply you should have no problems with the default setup.

Comment: Yes I don't have any problems with the default setup. The reason I want to do that is that we will deploy our website to production with port 8630. So I was thinking it would be best if we make our develop environment consistent with production env. Also I didn't see any document saying it's a bad practice..

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue with IIS 10 Express on Windows 10. With [Jexus Manager](http://jexusmanager.exe) you can easily set a site to run at port 8630 (if nothing else uses that port).

Comment: Thanks @LexLi . unfortunately in my case third party tool is not an option...